# PowerShell: Check a folder for changes and if so, send an e-mail

Tags: powershell, email, notifications, smtp, directory

I have a colleague with loads of creative ideas, but I've got no talent with PowerShell. He wants a folder to be checked regularly for changes. As soon as a new file has been added to the folder, he wants to be notified via mail. So, I guess I need a PS script for that.

I have absolutely no idea on how to do this, though.

I found the following code - can this be altered to do the job?

```
Param (
    [string]$Path = "C:\Test",
    [string]$SMTPServer = "SMTP IP",
    [string]$From = "MyMail@domain.com",
    [string]$To = "MyMail@domain.com",
    [string]$Subject = "New stuff!"
)

$SMTPMessage = @{
    To         = $To
    From       = $From
    Subject    = "$Subject at $Path"
    Smtpserver = $SMTPServer
}

$File = Get-ChildItem $Path | Where { $_.LastWriteTime -ge [datetime]::Now.AddMinutes(-1) }
If ($File) {
    $SMTPBody = "`nThe following files have recently been added/changed:`n`n"
    $File | ForEach { $SMTPBody += "$($_.FullName)`n" }
    Send-MailMessage @SMTPMessage -Body $SMTPBody
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You don't have to check your folder for changes. Use a [`FileSystemWatcher`](https://mcpmag.com/articles/2015/09/24/changes-to-a-folder-using-powershell.aspx) instead.

Comment: This should help you : https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Powershell-FileSystemWatche-dfd7084b

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get notified about changes on a particular folder, and/or its sub items, one can use .Net Frameworks [`FileSystemWatcher`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) class. Instantiate a new one with PowerShell using:

```
$pattern = "*.*"
$watcherProperties = @{
    IncludeSubdirectories = $false;
    NotifyFilter = [IO.NotifyFilters]'FileName, LastWrite'
    }
$watcher = New-Object IO.FileSystemWatcher $Path, $pattern -Property @watcherProperties
```

Then, to get notified about changes, register an event using [`Register-ObjectEvent`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/register-objectevent?view=powershell-5.1) and add your mail block:

```
Register-ObjectEvent $watcher Created -SourceIdentifier FileCreated -Action {
    $SMTPBody = "`nThe following file have recently been added/changed:`n`n$($Event.SourceEventArgs.Name)"
    Send-MailMessage @SMTPMessage -Body $SMTPBody}
}
```

While this is a nice solution to get automatically notified, without heavy loops, it also has some drawbacks. In this configuration you would get one mail for **every** file changed.
Moving directories with bunches of files would result in - bunches of mails.

You can read more about [`FileSystemWatcher`s](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) here:

- [Script Center: PowerShell FileSystemWatcher - Script by Bigteddy](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Powershell-FileSystemWatche-dfd7084b)
- [Tracking Changes to a Folder Using PowerShell - Blog article by Boe Prox](https://mcpmag.com/articles/2015/09/24/changes-to-a-folder-using-powershell.aspx)